# How to connect to Cloud SQL Postgres DB from App Engine (Node.js) in different project?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Cloud SQL Postgres db and App Engine are located in different Google Cloud projects. How to connect from App Engine to Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Simply grant the `Cloud SQL CLient` role to your AppEngine service account, in the project where Cloud SQL instance is.

More details on [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard#configuring)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to do the following two things:

1. Make sure the Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled for the project you are calling from
2. Make sure the service (or user) account has the `Cloud SQL client` IAM role (or higher) for the project the database is in